# How to change event log properties from WiX script?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, event-log

Our WiX script currently creates an event log source using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58538/how-do-you-create-an-event-log-source-using-wix).

However, the log is created with default values for the **Maximum log size** and how it behaves when the log is full (e.g. **Overwrite events as needed**).

Is there an easy way to change those values when creating the source? I'm guessing it would require creating a custom action, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way or if such an action already exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've looked in the WiX CHM and did not see a field for specifying the maximum log size and how it behaves when full.  But, I did find this entry which I think will help, and allow you to skip using a custom action:
http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02026.html

So, I think for you:

1. Create the EventSource, possibly in the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog`), and configure it to your liking
2. Export the key
3. Use the program listed here to convert the REG file to a WiX authoring: [How to generate WiX XML from a .reg file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269423/how-to-generate-wix-xml-from-a-reg-file/270442#270442)

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to require a reboot for the changes to be applied, which I'd like to avoid. The System.Diagnostics.EventLog object can modify the values without requiring a reboot. I was hoping to find a way to do that, but it looks like writing my own custom action might be the only option.

Comment: @ToddRopog If you end up creating a custom action, could you share it here, please?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Sorry, I don't think I ever did, but I haven't used WiX in a long time.