# Registering COM EXE with WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I created a solution with two new projects: `ATLProject1` which is a COM dll and `ATLProject2` which is a COM EXE. To both projects added same simple class with single method.

Added both to WIX setup project (this is an existing setup project that already installs other COM dlls. I'm just using it for this test).

Added following lines to product.wxs:

```
        <Component Id="ATLProject1.dll" Guid="{...}">
          <File Id="ATLProject1.dll" Name="ATLProject1.dll" KeyPath="yes" SelfRegCost="0" Source="$(var.TargetDir)\ATLProject1.dll" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="ATLProject2.exe" Guid="{...}">
          <File Id="ATLProject2.exe" Name="ATLProject2.exe" KeyPath="yes" SelfRegCost="0" Source="$(var.TargetDir)\ATLProject2.exe" />
        </Component>
```

and also

```
  <ComponentRef Id="ATLProject1.dll" />
  <ComponentRef Id="ATLProject2.exe" />
```

The file also has these lines:

```
<EnsureTable Id="PublishComponent"/>
<EnsureTable Id="Condition"/>
<EnsureTable Id="TypeLib"/>
<EnsureTable Id="Class"/>
<EnsureTable Id="Extension"/>
```

When running the setup I get error: **"Module ATLProject2.exe failed to register. HRESULT -2147024769"** (hex 0x8007007f the specified procedure cannot be found).

If I remove `ATLProject2` from setup, it succeeds and `ATLProject1` is correctly registered in registry (this is without generating registry information e.g. using heat, it just works).

Should exe component be treated differently?

I found [this 10 year old post suggesting heat.exe does not treat COM exe as COM](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Heat-and-exe-COM-objects-td3908196.html). If this is the problem, Not sure if this is still the case?

Comment: Have a look at WiX `TypeLib` element, and check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567925/typelib-generation-and-installation-with-wix) as well

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Installer does not recommend using [SelfReg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/selfreg-table) to register at install time. Instead, adding the registration to your .wxs code or capturing the registration at build time is highly recommended.

To add the registration manually, you don't use `EnsureTable`, you use the COM related elements (like `Class`, `ProgId`, `TypeLib`). It can be tedious but will be far more robust than trying to selfreg during installation.

Unfortunately, the alternative to capture the registration during build using `heat.exe` (provided in the WiX toolset) does not support capturing from executables. If you are open to a commercial solution, we (FireGiant) developed an [alternative to `heat.exe` that can capture executable registration](https://www.firegiant.com/products/wix-expansion-pack/#heatwave-harvesting) (and much more). That [advanced harvesting solution has more documentation on the FireGiant site](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/wep-documentation/harvesting/).

Answer (score 0):

***RegServer Switch***: COM EXE files are normally self-registered via the **`/RegServer`** switch as in:

```
MyBinary.exe /RegServer
```

In other words EXE files are not registered via the normal **`regsvr32.exe`** mechanism. This is the tool used to register COM dll's and OCX files, but it does not handle EXE files. There is also an **`/UnRegServer`** switch to unregister EXE COM files - for the executables that support **`/RegServer`** (**`which is not all COM EXE files - it could be missing as a feature`**).

***Self-Registration***: Self-Registration is not ideal to register COM files, and here is a write-up of why this is the case: **[MSI register dll - Self-Registration considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129816/msi-register-dll-self-registration-considered-harmful/6141538#6141538)**. In MSI one extracts the COM registry data and populates a number of special COM-tables to allow the registration of the COM server in a way that supports advanced features such as rollback. I don't like the COM extract either ([risk of self-repair problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair/6066263#6066263), [more on self-repair problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716108/what-do-i-do-when-launching-an-application-triggers-repeating-endless-windows-i/45716110#45716110)), but it helps in most cases - especially when there are dependencies that can trigger registration problems. Moreover it is the way COM files are supposed to be registered in MSI. It is the standard. I should note that some COM settings go into the Registry table still - since there are no dedicated COM-related tables for them.

***heat.exe***: WiX's own **`heat.exe`** tool now can extract COM data from dll files and ocx files (32-bit). But it does not seem to work for EXE COM files - I am not sure why:

```
heat.exe file MyCOMDll.dll -out MyCOMDll.wxs
```

***RegSpy2.exe***: There is a tool you can use to extract COM registration information from both **DLL**, **OCX** and **EXE** files. It can be downloaded from here: http://www.installsite.org/files/iswi/RegSpy2.zip. [Here is the main page listing numerous tools](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/tt_analyze.htm). The **`RegSpy tool`** is written by **Phil Wilson** - MSI Expert and author of [The Definitive Guide to Windows Installer](https://books.google.no/books?id=JvxAtZ8KU9QC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) ([APress](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781590592977)).

Here is how to extract the COM data from a COM executable (if you get no data, try unregistering the file first and then running **`regspy.exe`**):

```
RegSpy.exe MyBinary.exe /RegServer >> RegistryOutput.reg
```

The exported **`*.reg file`** can then be converted to WiX elements. This is not an easy process. Using the WiX tool **`heat.exe`** does not populate the proper COM tables, but rather puts everything in the **`Registry table`** (which will work though, barring MSI validation errors):

```
heat.exe reg MyCOMRegistryData.reg -out MyWiXFile.wxs -sfrag -suid
```

There used to be a tool called Tallow that converted reg files to WiX COM registration, but this tool is no longer anywhere to be found. I am not aware of any other ways to generate it short of writing it yourself, or download [another deployment tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) and import the COM data or extract it and decompile the generated MSI with **`dark.exe`** and take out the WiX markup. Or figure out how **`heat.exe`** writes its WiX XML output with COM data and adapt that to process the output from RegSpy.exe.

***UPDATE***: Throwing in a link to **Paraffin**: https://github.com/Wintellect/Paraffin. This is supposedly a "better Tallow". I am not sure what it supports in terms of COM-extract. My quick test seemed to indicate it doesn't support COM extraction at all, but supports auto-generating WiX markup and add and remove files for updates.

***Custom Actions***: It is possible to register your COM EXE by means of a custom action that calls the **`/RegServer`** switch as well, though this is not recommended for all the reasons listed in the link above ([self-registration considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129816/msi-register-dll-self-registration-considered-harmful/6141538#6141538)).

---

***Some Links***:

- [Adding a .reg file to registry WIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988805/adding-a-reg-file-to-registry-wix/11988983#11988983)
- [How to generate WiX XML from a .reg file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269423/how-to-generate-wix-xml-from-a-reg-file)

Comment: https://github.com/nirbar/WixHeatATLHarvesterExtension - some malware hits upon download. Just "unknown reputation". Should be OK.

Comment: There has got to be an easier way to deal with creating MSI for active x dlls.....