# How can I use regcap for a 64-bit DLL file

Tags: windows, dll, com, windows-installer, registry

I want to capture what `regsvr32 mycomthingie.dll` does into a .reg file. I downloaded [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects), and trying to use regcap.exe for this purpose. It simply quits without an error message and no reg file is created. I tried in both normal and admin cmd prompts. I suspect the problem is that the target dll is 64bit but regcap.exe is a 32bit executable.

I couldn't find a 64-bit version of this tool, so my question is, what can I do if the only version of the DLL I have is compiled as 64bit (PE32+)

Comment: [Been a while since I looked at COM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55459208/129130). Might look more later, but please have a look here: https://github.com/nirbar/WixHeatATLHarvesterExtension (this is for WiX, but the code might help you - or you could translate the entries to *.reg - or maybe locate a 32-bit version of the dll - if it exists - and see if the GUIDs match? Just off the top of my head - not that carefully reasoned. [Trial versions of commercial MSI tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) could help you? They would be able to extract the data?

Comment: Hi again, I added a suggestion below. Please have a look (unless you have found another solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***UPDATE***: [How to open a Windows binary as a resource in Visual Studio 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_xcKg7WM4Y) (use Visual Studio to extract *.RGS files from a COM binary - see comments below).

---

Despite little testing, let me add this for the record.

***WixHeatATLHarvesterExtension***: Try to download the **`WixHeatATLHarvesterExtension`**: https://github.com/nirbar/WixHeatATLHarvesterExtension

This will extend WiX's normal **`heat.exe`** tool with a new command:

```
heat atlcom "c:\vsFlex8n.ocx" -out vsFlex8n_COM.wxs
```

This appears to work for 64-bit COM files. **What you get is an exported WiX source file and not a reg file though - sorry**. You can construct a reg file manually though? Based on the WiX source you can convert to reg? Or just switch to using WiX if you don't already? [Wix quick start link collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864).

***Procedure:***

1. ***Build***: To get to this you need to download and build the solution above.
2. ***Install***: Once built you install the **`ATLHarvester.msi`** and this will put the components in place in the WiX installation directory. You need to download and install [the WiX toolkit](https://wixtoolset.org/releases/) first though.
3. ***Configure***: Now you can also add the WiX bin folder to your environment path, but that is not necessary if you use the full path to **`heat.exe`** (last part untested). You should also be able to use the WIX environment variable: **`%WIX%\bin\heat.exe`** (type **`set`** in a **`cmd.exe`** to see the WIX variable path).

If you upload the dll somewhere with dependencies I can try it. These 64-bit COM files have been a serious grief before for me too.

---

Also found these projects that didn't work properly for me outright:

- https://github.com/PhilJollans/RegSpy
- https://github.com/PhilJollans/RegToInno

Comment: I didn't have time to try your solution, but it does looks promising and yes my original goal was to use `heat` in a 64-bit COM DLL.
I ended up using https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html to snapshot the registry and use `regsvr32` and compare the snapshots, export a reg file then use heat in the reg file.

Comment: Sounds good. I suppose we should also mention that you can locate the [*.RGS source files](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6319/Registry-Map-for-RGS-files) if you have access to the source for the 64-bit COM components. As an option for others who find this.

Comment: Now that I think about it: you should be able to get to the *.RGS content by opening the binary as a resource in Visual Studio. Just copy the text and dump into notepad or equivalent. If nothing else, as a form of control and double checking.

Comment: [How to open a Windows binary as a resource in Visual Studio 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_xcKg7WM4Y).